# Best way to analyse two experiments

Tags: sampling, normalization, aggregation, function

I'm looking for help/indication on approaching a data integration problem.

I have a dose-response curve that is described by a log curve. Because of measurement difficulties, the dose and response can't be measured in the same experiment, for high and low doses. I can estimate the function's slope at low and high doses using the same sampling cohort, but not at the same time or with the same technique.

What is the best approach to normalising the data in a way that can be used in the same dose-response function?